# How to do fresh install 20.04

Tags: 20.04

Can anyone provide simple instructions...just a clean wipe and fresh install to 20.04 (from 18.04).

Can it be done without any USB/DVD/etc.?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can upgrade without external storage following this tutorial:
https://ubuntu.com/blog/how-to-upgrade-from-ubuntu-18-04-lts-to-20-04-lts-today
If you want clean wipe, you need to boot installer from external storage.